# JavaFX ComboBox Displayed Item Font Size

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, combobox, formatting

I am using a combo box to display let the user pick between a few items in my JavaFX program but am having some trouble formatting it. I am able to change the font size of the items in the drop down list by modifying the cell factory but I am unable to figure out how to change the size of the singe displayed item when the combo box is sitting there not being used. I want to make the text a bit bigger the match the items in the list that I formatted in the cell factory. Below is a picture of what I am talking about. As you can see, the displayed item's font size is much smaller than the items in the drop down list. Any help is much appreciated.

CODE:

```
ComboBox countyList = new ComboBox(counties);
    countyList.setPrefWidth(400);
    countyList.setPrefHeight(35);
    countyList.setCellFactory(l -> new ListCell<String>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
                setFont(HeldFont.build(15));
            }
        }

    });
```

[image: Picture of UI]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the following:

```
countyList.setButtonCell(new ListCell(){

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty); 
            if(empty || item==null){
                setStyle("-fx-font-size:15");
            } else {
                setStyle("-fx-font-size:15");
                setText(item.toString());
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad it helped ))